JDBC Connectivity issue (jar file)
Objective
I'm trying to connect to a MySQL database using Java,
Issue
My code isn't working despite adding the MySQL Connector/J JAR file to the referenced libraries.
Code:
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jdbc_db", "root", "password");
        System.out.println("driver loading..............."); 
    }
}

Error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Configuration:

Java Version : Java 17
Connector/J Version: Connector/J 8.0.28
MYSQL Version: MySQL 8.0.
Platform Windows 11.
IDE: VS-Code.
Execution: From IDE

# Stack Trace
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
        at App.main(App.java:6)

Steps Taken:

Added the MySQL Connector/J JAR file to the referenced libraries.
Verified that the JAR file is in the correct location.
Checked the Java code for syntax errors.

Question:
Why is my Java code not working despite adding the MySQL Connector/J JAR file to the referenced libraries?

If you're using VSC, I would use it in conjunction with Maven. It will ensure the driver is in the right place at the right time

Gradle is another option.

Be aware, once you've solved your classpath problem, that Class.forName is no longer necessary for modern drivers.

@NidhiKalouni You say you have the right jar on the classpath. But you don't. That's the one, and only, explanation for the error you get. Given that you haven't specifically mentioned how you are running your app so that you get the stacktrace you pasted, helping you from here is equivalent to 'how do I run my own java apps and work with external deps' which is overly broad, and best covered by basic tutorials.

Related: How can I obtain MySQL Connector Java Maven Dependency

in such kind of question, "adding the MySQL Connector/J JAR file to the referenced libraries" does not help (even if duplicated) - better explain how exactly you did it (maybe the mentioned "referenced libraries" are only used for compilation, not at runtime?! Or is it the wrong file that is being added?!)

Classpath
Check your classpath. You must add libraries/dependencies like a JDBC driver to your classpath.
Many Java programmers use a dependency management tool such as Apache Maven or Gradle to obtain and install a library such as a JDBC driver. For example, in a Maven POM configuration file:
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysql/mysql-connector-j -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.33</version>
</dependency>

If you are not using any build tool you must ensure that your classpath includes your dependencies.
javac -cp /path/to/library1.jar:/path/to/library2.jar YourClass.java


some notes mostly regarding the second code snippet: 1) the compiler (javac) does not need the driver class since it is being loaded by name (forName(String)); 2) the Exception is a runtime problem (java); 3) it is often (always?) better to include the actual (or at least the source) directory
